# github actions share values between workflows

Tags: github-actions

I have two workflows within the same project in gihub.  The first workflow create and publishes a docker image on docker hub and is automatic on push.  The second workflow which is manual should pull the docker image published in workflow 1 and deploy it on a cluster.  As part of the first workflow I need to share a docker image tag from workflow 1 to workflow 2.  How do I do that.  I checked environment variables, but from what I have seen its localized to a workflow and you cannot share it between workflows.

Comment: How's the tag generated (and will the second workflow have the same information used to generate it)? Will it just be the `:latest`?

Comment: tag is generated using the github action https://github.com/docker/metadata-action.  Its basically the sha of the commit, not `:latest`.  Also it could be that there are multiple runs of the first workflows, but the second one will run manually whenever required, so it should pick up the latest published image.

Comment: _"it should pick up the latest published image"_ - unless you've specifically turned it off that action does handle the [latest tag](https://github.com/docker/metadata-action#latest-tag).

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of a reusable workflow using the `workflow_call` trigger and pass it the tag as an input

docs for reusable workflow: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows.

If these workflows run at different times, you can store the tag string as an artifact and then reference it later.

docs for artifact: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/storing-workflow-data-as-artifacts